# Embedded Python: Getting func obj from imported module

Tags: c++, python, boost

I have a Python module that I import from my C++ code (I'm embedding Python). This module contains a function `create()` that I want to get a hold of in my C++ code (i.e. store it in a `boost::python::object` instance).

Here's what I tried. A run-time error occurs on the indicated line in my C++ code. The error occurs because it is unable to find the "hero.create" function inside the main namespace.

**C++ code**

```
namespace python = boost::python;

// Standard Boost.Python code
// Here I just create objects for the main module and its namespace

python::object main_module(
    python::handle<>(python::borrowed(PyImport_AddModule("__main__")))
);

python::object main_namespace(main_module.attr("__dict__"));


// This is my code
//

python::exec("import hero", main_namespace, main_namespace);
python::object func(main_namespace["hero.create"]); // Run-time error
Entity ent = python::extract<Entity>(func());

// I also tried doing this, but it didn't work either...
// python::object func(main_namespace["hero"].attr("__dict__")["create"]);

// However, if I do this, all works fine...
// python::exec("from hero import create", main_namespace, main_namespace);
// python::object func(main_namespace["create"]); // No error
```

**Python code (*hero.py*)**

```
from entity import Entity

def create():
    ent = Entity()
    # ...
    return ent
```

Comment: What do you get if you print out `hero.__dict__`? Did you try just `main_namespace["hero"].attr("create")`? I'd bet you don't use `class.member` to access it from C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do `main_namespace["hero"].attr("create")`. Import creates only one name in the namespace, and it's a module object. Names cannot have dots in them — `.` is a getattr operator — so `hero.create` is the same as `getattr(hero, 'create')`.

You could also use `boost::python::import` directly, instead of `exec`ing import statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also for the tip regarding python::import. It looks much cleaner now. :)

Comment: I opened a follow-up question ([6816373](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816373)). Could you please take a look at it, if you are willing to?