# What happens during and after boost::python::import?

Tags: c++, python, boost

The Boost documentation does not specify this. When I use [boost::python::import](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/python/doc/v2/import.html#import-spec), where exactly is the specified module imported? My guess would be in `'__main__'` (just to make sure).

Also, what happens when the module object goes out of scope? Given the wording in Boost's docs — "Returns: An instance of object which holds a reference to the imported module" — I would guess only the reference goes out of scope, the module object is still found within `'__main__'` (or wherever it was imported).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying mechanism is [`PyImport_ImportModule`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/import.html), and no, it doesn't touch `__main__`. Successfully imported modules are inserted into [`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.modules) dict, so the object is not freed when you DECREF what the function returns — there is still at least that one reference alive.